# lxd init fails on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus

Tags: 16.04, uefi, snap, lxd

When I use lxd, it fails on `lxd init` .

```
$ snap install lxd
lxd 3.0.0 from 'canonical' installed
$ lxd init
Error: Failed to connect to local LXD: Get http://unix.socket/1.0: dial unix 
/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

I have the following on my computer:

```
$ snapcraft --version
snapcraft, version 2.42.1
$ uname -a
4.13.0-43-generic #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 17 12:56:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I don't know if this is relevant, but my computer uses Intel i7-7500U and has Secure Boot UEFI.

Below is output of more commands:

```
$ snap services lxd
Service     Startup  Current
lxd.daemon  enabled  active
$ snap logs lxd.daemon
2018-05-28T22:22:42Z lxd.daemon[1404]:   5: fd:  11: pids
2018-05-28T22:22:42Z lxd.daemon[1404]:   6: fd:  12: perf_event
2018-05-28T22:22:42Z lxd.daemon[1404]:   7: fd:  13: hugetlb
2018-05-28T22:22:42Z lxd.daemon[1404]:   8: fd:  14: cpu,cpuacct
2018-05-28T22:22:42Z lxd.daemon[1404]:   9: fd:  15: freezer
2018-05-28T22:22:42Z lxd.daemon[1404]:  10: fd:  16: net_cls,net_prio
2018-05-28T22:22:42Z lxd.daemon[1404]:  11: fd:  17: name=systemd
2018-05-28T22:22:42Z lxd.daemon[1404]: lvl=warn msg="CGroup memory swap accounting is disabled, swap limits will be ignored." t=2018-05-28T22:22:42+0000
2018-05-28T22:22:42Z lxd.daemon[1404]: lvl=warn msg="Failed to update instance types: Get https://images.linuxcontainers.org/meta/instance-types/.yaml: lookup images.linuxcontainers.org on [::1]:53: dial udp [::1]:53: connect: cannot assign requested address" t=2018-05-28T22:22:42+0000
2018-05-28T22:22:43Z lxd.daemon[1404]: => LXD is ready
$ lxd init
Error: Failed to connect to local LXD: Get http://unix.socket/1.0: dial unix /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket: connect: permission denied
```

Does lxd snap requires ipv6? Can I force ipv4? Is something else wrong?

Edit:

```
$ groups myusername 
 myusername : myusername adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare lxd
```

I am a member of lxd group. but

```
$ groups 
 myusername adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

has no lxd. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

When you run the command `lxd init` and there is an error, you get a reason,

```
$ lxd init
Error: Failed to connect to local LXD: Get http://unix.socket/1.0: dial unix 
/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket: connect: THE_REASON
```

1. Reason **no such file or directory** means that the LXD service did not start yet (may need to wait a bit or just manually start it).
2. Reason **permission denied** means that your current account does not below to the group `lxd`, therefore is not permitted to access the socket `/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket`.

In this case, run `groups` to see whether your account is member of the `lxd` group. If you are member of the `lxd` group, then you need to log out and then log it. If you are not member of the `lxd` group, then run

```
$ sudo usermod --append --groups lxd myusername
```

and then log out and login again.

Comment: `$ groups myusername` \n \n `myusername : myusername adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare lxd` \n \n I am a member of lxd group. but \n \n `$ groups` \n `myusername adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare` \n \n has no lxd. What does it mean?

Comment: If you run `groups myusername` and `groups`, they must have identical output. 
Unless you are not logged in as use `myusername`.

Answer (score 0):

Your group additions haven't applied. Log out and log back in to do so. But yes, looks like a permissions issue - lxd init needs to be run as sudo IIRC anyway